# Choose between 2 Beans in runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, javabeans

I am using Java Spring.

I have a Bean that I can create in 2 different ways which will be decided on runtime only, using a parameter (boolean) from `.yml` file.

The easy way to solve it is to use a simple `if` condition on the parameter and call the function needed according to it's value.

Is there a way to do it using Spring annotation and not on my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using the [ConditionalOnProperty](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html) annotation.

```java
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "key", havingValue = "true")
doThis() {

}

@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "key", havingValue = "false")
doThat() {

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
What does the "name" is referring to?

Comment: Name is referring to the property itself as defined in YAML. It's also represented by `value` which is common with annotations. The two are interchangeable.

Comment: The issue still didn't solved. I want to create a bean with the same name and I can't do that. I have a Boolean variable which the user injects on runtime and by it's value I need to change the configuration. But at last, the bean is the same object..